# Join tables from different databases?

Tags: sqlite.swift

I'm using the Sqlite.swift framework to build a WatchOS app. I have followed some iOS guidelines and separated the static data from the user-generated data, so now I have two databases each with one table and a common key.

Is it possible to join the tables from different databases? I tried this:

```
 let query2 = kanaTable.join(.leftOuter, userTable!, on: kanaTable[kana_id] == (userTable?[kana_id])!)

    for kanaChar in try! db.prepare(query2) {

      print("kana_id: \(kanaChar[kana_id]), kana: \(kanaChar[kana]), romaji: \(kanaChar[romaji]), group: \(kanaChar[kana_group])")

    }
```

But it's not compiling because I think it is looking for userTable from the db, but userTable is from the second db. How do I change my code to point to the right database?

Comment: Do you specifically need two separate databases?  Why not have a single database with two different tables?

Comment: Yes that's what I've done now. But I thought it would be more elegant to do a join rather than manually hacking together my own join.